# Use of the right Jacobian in SO(3) to approximate $\exp([\phi + \delta\phi]_\times)$

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization, lie-groups, matrix-exponential

I'm currently starting with Lie Groups, focusing on their applications in estimation (I have an engineering background). Having a look at posts like: "[jacobian involving SO(3) exponential map: $\log(R\exp(m))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301533/jacobian-involving-so3-exponential-map-logr-expm/2221516#2221516)" is stated that the right Jacobian is given by:
$$ \mathtt{J}_r(\phi) =  \frac{\partial\exp([\phi]_\times)}{\partial \phi} = I - \frac{1-\cos(\Vert\phi\Vert)}{\Vert\phi\Vert^2}[\phi]_\times + \frac{\Vert\phi\Vert-\sin(\Vert\phi\Vert)}{\Vert\phi\Vert^3}[\phi]_\times^2$$

However, I'm having difficulties to understand how by using the right Jacobian $\mathtt{J}_r(\phi)$ we are able to relate an additive perturbation $\delta\phi$ in the tangent space to a multiplicative perturbation on the manifold SO(3).

Given that a first-order approximation of $\exp([\phi + \delta\phi]_\times)$, as noted in [On-Manifold Preintegration for Real-Time
Visual-Inertial Odometry](https://www.ifi.uzh.ch/dam/jcr:67a6caa8-84e8-4f9b-9744-aefaec68d308/TRO16_forster.pdf) (page 4), is given by:

$$\exp([\phi + \delta\phi]_\times) \approx \exp([\phi]_\times) \exp([\mathtt{J}_r(\phi)\delta\phi]_\times)$$

On the one hand, I don't understand how we can compute the skew matrix $[\cdot]_\times$ of $\mathtt{J}_r\delta\phi$ because I believe that $\mathtt{J}_r\delta\phi$ is already a matrix and not a vector $\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

On the other hand, given that $\mathtt{J}_r(\phi) =  \frac{\partial\exp([\phi]_\times)}{\partial \phi}\to$ Doesn't this mean that ($\mathtt{J}_r(\phi)\delta\phi$) belongs to SO(3)? Following this, would the following expression be a valid way of computing the first-order approximation?:
$$ \exp([\phi + \delta\phi]_\times) \approx \exp([\phi]_\times)\mathtt{J}_r(\phi)\delta\phi$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find an explanation?

Comment: @FourierFlux Yes, now that I have recalled this question I will post a longer answer, but the main point is that $$\mathtt{J}_r(\phi)=\left.\frac{\partial\mathrm{Log}(\mathrm{Exp}(\phi)^{-1}\mathrm{Exp}(\phi+\delta\phi))}{\partial\delta\phi}\right|_{\delta\phi=0}~,$$thus being a $6\times6$ Jacobian which maps differential increments in the Lie Algebra (here denoted as $\delta\phi$), to the local tangent plane rep. of a infinitesimal composition applied to the right i.e. locally approximating: $$\mathrm{Exp}(\phi+\delta\phi) \approx \mathrm{Exp}(\phi)\mathrm{Exp}(\mathtt{J}_r(\phi)\delta\phi)$$

Comment: @FourierFlux a typo: I meant a $3\times3$ Jacobian.

Comment: Does this have something to do with how phi evaluated at 0? I'm still not seeing it in mind how this works out.

Comment: @FourierFlux yes, this has to do with the classic definition of the derivative in Euclidean spaces:
$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\left.\frac{\partial f(x+h)}{\partial h}\right|_0~,$$
on smooth manifolds:
$$\left.\frac{\partial f(x\oplus h)\ominus f(x)}{\partial h}\right|_0$$
where $f:=\text{Exp}\to f(x+h):=\text{Exp}(x+h)$ and $f(y)\ominus f(x):=\text{Log}(\text{Exp}(x)^{-1}\text{Exp}(y))$.
This is better explained in Sec.II of [Micro Lie theory, Solà et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.01537) which is of great help (all of it). The particularization to one manifold is in Sec. III.

Comment: @FourierFlux concretely at Sec. II. G

Comment: Thanks, I will look. I think I got it since matrix log of I is 0 so finite difference approximation gives the identity after substitution.