# Why are there two different (left) Jacobian definitions of SO(3) and what are the differences?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, rotations, rigid-transformation

I read about the exponential map of SE(3), in which the left Jacobian of SO(3) is used. I found two different definitions.

Using the a common notation (rotation axis: $\boldsymbol{\omega}$, rotation angle: $\theta$), the **first definition** is

$$\boldsymbol{J}_A(\theta) = \frac{\sin{\theta}}{\theta} \boldsymbol{I} + \left( 1 - \frac{\sin{\theta}}{\theta} \right) \boldsymbol{\omega}\boldsymbol{\omega}^T + \frac{1 - \cos{\theta}}{\theta} [\boldsymbol{\omega}]$$

and it is used by

1. T. D. Barfoot and P. T. Furgale, "Associating Uncertainty With Three-Dimensional Poses for Use in Estimation Problems," in IEEE Transactions on Robotics, vol. 30, no. 3, pp. 679-693, June 2014, doi: 10.1109/TRO.2014.2298059. URL: http://ncfrn.mcgill.ca/members/pubs/barfoot_tro14.pdf

   - Exponential and logarithmic map of SE(3) are defined in Appendix B.
   - Jacobian in Equation 98.
2. J. Solà, J. Deray, and D. Atchuthan, "A micro Lie theory for state estimation in robotics". Technical report. URL: https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.01537

   - Exponential and logarithmic of SE(3) map are defined in Appendix D.
   - Jacobian in Equation 145.

A **second definition** is

$$\boldsymbol{J}_B(\theta) = \theta \boldsymbol{I} + \left( \theta - \sin{\theta} \right) [\boldsymbol{\omega}]^2 + \left( 1 - \cos{\theta} \right) [\boldsymbol{\omega}]$$

from

K. M. Lynch and F. C. Park, "Modern Robotics: Mechanics, Planning, and Control". URL: http://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/images/2/25/MR-v2.pdf

- Exponential map of SE(3) is defined in Section 3.3.3.1
- Jacobian in Equation 3.87.

Both representations probably have their justification. Where are they used? What are the differences?

edit: It seems that $J_A(\theta) = \frac{J_B(\theta)}{\theta}$

edit2: In fact, the Jacobians are exactly the same, but the definition of the exponential map of SE(3) is different. In the first definition, the translation components are not multiplied by the angle. In the second definition they are. The second definition originates from screw theory.

Comment: The question is more about $SO(3)$ only rather than about $SE(3)$. You may want to edit the title to attract proper attention. Instead of throwing at us all those links and formula numbers you also may want to extract the essential defintions/names from those papers and highlight the problem. As far as I can tell it is about the [left Jacobian of $SO(3)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2968295/949989). I did such calculations once in a quaternion setting and am not totally unfamilar with those matters. The question is however too hard to read at the moment.

Comment: At first glance: In the MSE link I gave the Jacobian looks more like the one from Baarfoot / Furgale.

Comment: Unequivocally cool with [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula)?

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I tried to simplify the question. I would like to keep the references for my reference or is there a better way to keep track of it? Which essential definitions names should I clarify? The Jacobian from the link is indeed similar to Barfoot / Furgale, but it is the right Jacobian, while they provide the left Jacobian. A comparison of the two is provided by Sola et al. Only the sign of the last summand is different.

Comment: One of your authors is a member of this forum (he gave the answer in the like of my first comment). I suggest that you contact him. Best by commenting on his answer in the link. I tried to rederive some Jacobian formulas but found it much easier with quaternions. They are very convenient but might confuse you even more at the moment.

Comment: I think in the end it is an issue of the exponential coordinate definition of SE(3). Screw theory, which used more often in mechanics, defines exponential coordinates as some screw axis S (which contains information about translation and rotation axis) times the angle. While the other formulation, which is more often used in state estimation, defines exponential coordinates such that the translation component is not multiplied by the angle. The Jacobian of SO(3) is the same in both cases. However, the discussion helped me to understand that, so thank you very much!

Comment: I did not write an answer but I am intrigued now. If you want to post more details I'd be happy to look into them. With my favourite quaternions the Jacobians look very simple. I did not understand why they looked so different in those other papers despite the fact that axis-angle representation of a rotation matrix is practically the same as using a quaternion. Since I did not find a true "definition" of their Jacobians (only formulas) in all the links you gave I gave up. In reality I think one must start with left/right invariant vector fields to know what the Jacobian is there for.

Comment: As I said, my issue does not really seem to be related to the Jacobians. I think Sola et al. (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.01537.pdf) provide a good summary of Jacobians on Lie groups such as SO(3) (page 7, Section II-G). The concrete derivation of the Jacobians of SO(3) seem to be adopted from a book though and are only listed there.